# Recorded VBA Macros Appear in VBE but not in Macro List

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

I have been having tons of trouble with one macro-enabled file in particular. I have numerous Subroutines, all of which are Public and do not require arguments. These macros do not appear in the macro-list in the Developer Tab (Alt + F8), though.

Even stranger is that when I record a new macro to "This Workbook", the macro successfully creates a new Subroutine in a new Module in VBE, but it does not show up in the Macro List (Alt + F8).

I've had others on my team open the same file, and all the macros in the file appear in their macro list.

The issue seems to be contained to just me, and to just this one file. Macros for other VBA projects appear in the Macro List.

Comment: As an update, when I had someone on my team download the same file from SharePoint and then email it to me, I no longer had issues. I'm not sure if there is some security setting that is therefore getting triggered when I download from SharePoint (even though the SP site is on my trusted sites, and I have all my Macro settings to be fully enabled).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the wrong file is selected in the dropdown box?

[image]